# Privacy: Disallowing server reading user's time

Tags: security, browser, privacy, spoofing

If you go to [www.deviceinfo.me](https://www.deviceinfo.me), you'll see that the website is able to read your machine's local time. This is sensitive information because it says whereabouts you're located. Is there any way to disable the browser from dishing out this info? Are there any extensions that spoof it?

Comment: It's using Javascript to display the local time with something like date.toLocaleString() (more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). Bear in mind that when you go to a website, it knows your IP address which can usually identify the area in which you're located, check https://www.maxmind.com/en/locate-my-ip-address. However this can be somewhat mitigated by using a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to disable the browser from dishing out local time?

> This is sensitive information because it says whereabouts you're located.

Short answer is no. And it is not the browser dishing it out.

Firstly, it is worth noting that it is not using JavaScript to obtain this information
as I have JavaScript disabled by default and it can still retrieve the local time.

**So how does it get this information?**

- It is using your IP address (clearly you cannot prevent the website from knowing this as without it the website cannot serve the page back to you).
- From the IP address it uses geolocation of some kind (there are several different ways of doing this).

  In my case it returns a location of Manchester UK. As it happens it is not very accurate
  (about 35 miles out) as I'm using a shared wireless connection from my mobile. Knowing this I can deduce that it is getting the location from my ISP and that location is where my IP address happens to be registered.
- Once it has a location it is trivial to figure out the local date and time.

  In this case the local time is the same for Manchester and my location.

> Are there any extensions that spoof it?

You cannot spoof your IP address (well you can, but you would never get any data back from the internet).

You could use a VPN so that you exit point is in some other location. This is what users typically do if they are really concerned about their privacy on the internet.

Comment: I'm using a VPN and its servers are no where near my locale. So that website can't be using the IP information to get the local time on my machine. There must be another way.

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: Does that mean the server can read my time or it just displays it in my browser?

Comment: Can you block JavaScript and see what happens?

Comment: I disabled JavaScript and still that site is displaying my local time hmm